# How to load dynamically changed style in javascript through all of my pages

Tags: javascript, html, colors, styles

My code so far: http://pastebin.com/KTEF06Kf

I created a simple script that changes the colours of the page. (text background and main logo)
When i navigate to another page of my site, if the colours have been changed i want them to be loaded instead of the default colour.

How would i do this? I've tryed creating an onLoad function in the body of the other pages to call a function loadCol() which does the same thing as changeColour but with a preset colour instead of passing in from the box colour that was clicked.

Any clues of how i can acheive this. (Sorry if its poorly explained)

Answer (score 0):

When selecting something on one page, and making it persistent on all other pages, you'll need to store that value somewhere, as HTML in stateless and has no idea what was selected on the first page.

You can use cookies or local storage, or both, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage) has a polyfill for local storage that falls back to cookies.

You could also just pass the value in the links to the other pages with a hash or querystring:

```
mysite.com/page2?color=blue

mysite.com/page2#color=blue
```

Where you use javascript to change the anchors when a color is selected.

Comment: I'll have a look at the MDN, thanks for sharing will see how I go.

Comment: Tried MDN, still no luck. Though i may of made a mistake. 
here is what i've done now: http://pastebin.com/gvmap1P6
I've added a checkCC function to check if the colour has been changed. If it hasnt then it will be left default if it has it will be changed. But its not working, its detecting null all the time :|

checkCC is called on load of body.

Comment: You're setting it to null on the first line of the script, on the next line you're checking if it's null, which it of course is, as you just set it to null ?

Comment: Yeah i've got it working now. I didnt realise js ran through the entire file i thought it worked purely on the event handlers, fixed it anyway and got the whole thing working using MDN. Thanks